# How to distribute .d.ts file in npm package

Tags: visual-studio, typescript

I am trying to [include a .d.ts file in my npm package](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages) for [my (non-TypeScript) library](https://github.com/StephenCleary/iterjs).

I have the following in my `package.json`:

```
"typings": "./src/iter.d.ts",
```

But no matter what I put in `./src/iter.d.ts`, whenever I try to use it in Visual Studio, I always get a "Cannot find module 'iterjs'" message.

To reproduce, create a new TypeScript app in VS (I'm using 2015 with TS 1.8.4), do an `npm install iterjs`, and add the following to `app.ts`:

```
import iter from 'iterjs';
```

I've tried modifying the local copy of `iter.d.ts` (under `node_modules`) in a desperate attempt to get *anything working at all*; my local copy currently has only the following content:

```
export declare function bob(object: Object, property: string): boolean;
export default bob;
```

I can verify that Visual Studio is finding and reading the `iter.d.ts` file (I can see it being read in Process Monitor every time VS opens `app.ts`); however, there's apprently something in the `.d.ts` file it doesn't like. I have read about a dozen blog posts, gone through the Handbook, and a half-dozen TypeScript issues on the subject, and have tried about 20 different ways of exporting *anything* from the `.d.ts` file, but VS always just gives the same error (Cannot find module 'iterjs').

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node-like resolution of `.d.ts` files in NPM packages only works for type definitions in proper external module format. The `.d.ts` in your repository is in ambient module format, to convert it to the correct format remove `declare module "iter"` and prefix every symbol you wish to export with `export declare`, oh, and replace `export = iter` with `export default iter`. You can find additional info at https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Typings-for-npm-packages

Comment: I tried that, but I still get the same error. My current `iter.d.ts` file in `node_modules` has been modified to only have a single `export declare function bob...` and `export default bob`.

Comment: I installed your package from NPM and tried to import it, I'm using VSCode which complained that the `.d.ts` is not a module, and when I tried building with `tsc` it worked without complaint. This left me rather confused, so I tried to find a difference between some other NPM package typings that did work in VSCode and your ones, the only difference I could see was that your `.d.ts` had a UTF8 BOM while the other `d.ts` did not, so I tried removing the BOM, restarted VSCode and it didn't complain about your `d.ts` file anymore.

Comment: @StephenCleary The really strange thing is that I then put the UTF8 BOM back into your `.d.ts` and restarted VSCode again, and VSCode didn't complain this time.

Comment: OK, I published a new iterjs that uses external module format AFAIK, and with the BOM removed. Still getting the same error in Visual Studio.

Comment: @StephenCleary Just installed the updated version of your package from NPM and VSCode has no complaints about your `.d.ts` file. I'm using TypeScript 1.8.2.

Comment: Maybe I just don't know how to use TypeScript... I have a current version of VSCode; if I start in an empty directory, add a `tsconfig.json` copied from [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_tsconfigjson), run `npm install iterjs` in that dir, and then add an `app.ts` file with the line `import iter from 'iterjs';`, I get that same error in VSCode. Am I missing some step in setting up a TS project?

Comment: @StephenCleary Did you replace `"module": "amd"` with `"module": "commonjs"`?

Comment: Good catch. It is working in VSCode but still not in Visual Studio. At this point, I'm just chalking it up to some Visual Studio tooling bug. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does anyone know where the resource can be found not, it was moved (possibly multiple times) so the provided link doesn't work anymore.